# Mapping month to the number of the last day of that month

Tags: javascript

How would I map the month number to the number of the last day of that month, taking into consideration for February leap year the last day is 28 else it's 29

Comment: Can you use a time library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: Rule number 1 of writing your own date functionality: DO NOT WRITE YOUR OWN DATE FUNCTIONALITY.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can get the last day of the month like this:

```js
var month = 1; // Feb
var date = new Date((new Date()).getYear(), month + 1, 0);
alert("Last day of the month is: " + date.getDate());
```

Here it is as a function:

```
function getLastDayOfMonth(month) {
   return (new Date((new Date()).getYear(), month + 1, 0)).getDate();
}
```